# Why was I not asked for CVV in amazon.com for my debit card?

Tags: amazon

I ordered some items in amazon.com .Payment mode was through mastercard debit and I was not asked for cvv. This is the first time i added the debit card though I initially had my credit card details added to my account. The card is tied to a non US bank account.

Comment: This really isn't a security question but a payment card and payment processing question. I'm not sure where to direct this question.

Comment: I'm sure it varies quite a bit depending on the card and debit system being used, but in Canada, Interac cards don't have a CVV.  It may relate to that.